# Can "would be able to" be rephrased as "could" every time?

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs

I think 'could' has a lot more meanings than 'would be able to' does. But is it possible that one can consider that all the usages of 'would be able to' can be rephrased as just 'could'? In other words, does 'could' include 'would be able to'? (if you can ignore the slight politeness differences)

If not, could you make some examples for me?

Comment: Sounds possible to me. Check Longman's Advanced Learner's Dictionary - it contains a nice list for the application of 'could'.

Comment: *Even when I was only 6 I **could** swim*. That's fine, but even in the limited contexts where *Even when I was only 6 I **would be able to** swim* would be "syntactically acceptable", it wouldn't really mean the same thing. Another pair: *What you say **could** be true, but I doubt it* is perfectly natural English, but *What you say **would be able to** be true, but I doubt it* wouldn't really be acceptable to anyone in any context I can think of.

Comment: I think it might be more useful if you think in terms of ***is / was** able to* being "equivalent" to ***could***. Including both ***would*** and ***be able to*** just mixes up the senses of "irrealis" (***might*** happen / have happened, but actually *won't / didn't*), together with "**habitual** action in the past" and ***[cap]ability***. As a general principle, shorter is better. And there's no such principle as "more verbose / longer phrasing is more polite", which you seem to be implying.

Answer (score 1):

When you use *could* to express a conclusion that's purely logical and not dependent on a choice, it won't work very well with *would be able to*.

> I dropped it five minutes ago; it could be six feet in the water by now.
>
> I dropped it five minutes ago; it would be able to be six feet in the water by now (bad).