# Why is "would" used in this sentence? And how does it work?

Tags: word-usage, modal-verbs

If the sentence is without "would", is it right?

> Paul Merson has named three managers who he thinks **would** be able to win the Premier League title with current the Manchester United squad in a damning critique of Ole Gunnar Solskjaer.

What if "would be" is replaced with "is"?

> Paul Merson has named three managers who he thinks **are** able to win the Premier League title...

Comment: You need *some* kind of auxiliary verb before the infinitive element ***be able to** [do something]*. The word ***would*** could be replaced by, for example ***may, might*** without significantly changing the meaning, but it's worth noting that those alternatives usually imply rather less certainty than ***would***. On the other hand, replacing it with ***are*** or ***will be*** conveys effectively *absolute* certainty, whereas ***would*** really just implies ***very likely*** in many cases. Also note that ***would be able to*** can be entirely replaced by just ***could***.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can "would be able to" be rephrased as "could" every time?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/213205/can-would-be-able-to-be-rephrased-as-could-every-time)

Comment: So the use of would here shows less direct, right? If I replace it with "is", the speaker shows certainty?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. We could "justify" conditional ***would*** here as referring to the hypothetical condition ***if they were selected to run the team***, but in practice the only real implication of all that extra verbiage and "conditionality" (as opposed to *who he thinks **can** win*) is just "hedging" (maybe they could win, maybe they couldn't; there's always a degree of uncertainty in such contexts).

Comment: (Note that I had to write *who he thinks **can** win* for the more definite / direct version, because *who he thinks **will** win* would only work for ***one*** manager; they can't ***all*** be selected, and ***all*** win.)

Comment: "I will need two managers for this task", she said. Indirect speech: She said she **would need** two managers for the task.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the word "would" refers to *Paul Merson's* '***assumption***' that the three managers can win.

*Would* is used to **communicate about a hypothetical or an imagined event**, and it is frequently employed when that prospective circumstance will or will not occur.
*Which the sentence used the word "would" to make an assumption.*

**With Would**

> *Paul Merson* has named three managers who he thinks **would** be able to win the Premier League title with current the Manchester United
> squad in a damning critique of Ole Gunnar Solskjaer.

**Without would**

> *Paul Merson* has named three managers who he thinks **might** be able to win the Premier League title with current the Manchester United
> squad in a damning critique of Ole Gunnar Solskjaer.

- You would need to use a replacement word to complete the sentence.

Comment: So the use of would here shows less direct, right? If I replace it with "is", the speaker shows certainty?

Comment: Replace the would in the sentence? If yes, it's grammatically incorrect. Unless you remove the **be** in "Paul Merson has named three managers who he thinks would (be) able to."

Comment: Yes, I meant what is the difference between would and is? Paul Merson has named three managers who he thinks would be able/is able to win the Premier League title with current the Manchester United squad in a damning critique of Ole Gunnar Solskjaer

Comment: Sorry, I got busy with something. "Would" is simply an assumption of future events, and "is" is' classified as a kind of verb where it indicates occurrence or a state, or rather just simply a linking verb.

Answer (score 0):

Direct and indirect speech:

This is quite simple.

**Direct speech**: Paul Merson said,   "I **am naming** three managers I **think will be able** to win the Premier League title with current the Manchester United squad".

**Indirect speech**: Paul Merson **has named** three managers who he thinks **would be able** to win the Premier League title with current the Manchester United squad in a damning critique of Ole Gunnar Solskjaer.

**will** becomes **would** in indirect speech.